# npm publish fails giving PUT 404

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab, package

my .npmrc

```
 @bytap:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/
'//gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/:_authToken'="${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"
'//gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/37004905/packages/npm/:_authToken'="${GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN}"
```

my package.json

```
  "name": "@bytap/reuicom",
  "publishConfig": {
    "@bytap/registry": "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/37004905/packages/npm/"
  },
```

gitlab created group called as bytap and has project in it i.e. reuicom

running `GITLAB_AUTH_TOKEN=<Gitlab Deploy token> npm publish --verbose` getting this error

```
npm verb stack HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/@bytap%2freuicom - 404 Not Found
```

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/@bytap%2freuicom - 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@bytap/reuicom@0.1.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have registered "supericium" (npm adduser) as a username at the registry and be logged in (npm login) to publish under that scope.

```
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages
```

or

```
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an .npmrc file in the project which was overriding my user profile .npmrc settings. You can run `npm config list` to check the config values in effect and figure out anything goes wrong there or not.